# How do I track PWA installs from Play Store

Tags: android, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, tracking

I recently used [bubblewrap](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap/tree/main) to convert a PWA into a TWA and got it accepted into the Play Store. I currently track PWA installs by checking if the user's `display-mode` is `standalone`. However, this does not differentiate between in-browser installs and Play Store installs. I've considered sending Play Store app users to a different landing page then regular users and using either the `referrer` or `page location` to differentiate between the two, but this would involve modifying the `.aab`.  The user Agent doesn't appear to contain any additional data that would indicate that this is a Play Store install (which makes sense, since the app just runs in a browser window).

I cannot seem to find any way to track actual Play Store installs besides installing and using Firebase, which I believe should work but at this point it's no longer a PWA it's becoming an actual Android app and the lift required to do that is currently not possible.

Does anyone have any suggestions or resources? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to check :

public static boolean isInstalledViaGooglePlay(Context context) {
String installer = context.getPackageManager().getInstallerPackageName(context.getPackageName());
return "com.android.vending".equals(installer);
}

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll look into implementing this :)